# Undefined behaviour in C in i=i++; but what about i=++i;?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, sequence, c99, c17

I have studied sequence points (C99) and sequenced before /unsequenced (C17) and some other posts here in SO about this topic and its relation with undefined behaviour.

I think with C99 its ultra-clear that `i=i++;` and `i=++i;` both result in undefined behaviour, but according to C17 (or even C23) we have this:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the
> same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior
> is undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the subexpressions of an expression, the
> behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings.

And therefore, this:

```
i=i++;
```

Results in undefined behaviour because we have here to side effects the postfix ++ operator and the assignment, and **according to the answer of haccks** in this post [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior), we know that both side effects are unsequenced relative to each other so this results in undefined behaviour, but what about this:

```
i=++i;
```

At least for what I know here the incremented value of `i` should be used in the full expression, so we again have two side effects but now the side effect result of the pre-increment operator must be sequenced before the side effect result of the assignment operator, right?

And now my theory why, according to C11/C17/C23, "**i=++i;** is undefined behaviour is because the side effect result of the pre-increment operator is unsequenced relative to the value computation of "i" in the LHS right?

Comment: Looks like UB to me. C++ made it legal by sequencing the rhs of `=` before the lhs, but C doesn't do this. (C23 says "The evaluations of the operands are unsequenced.")

Comment: The phrase **"sequence point"** has a very specific meaning in the C standard. And (at least in C11) there's an informative annex C devoted to helping you find the sections related to sequence points. You should start there, because "sequenced" doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: The first sentence of the quoted language is pretty clear.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [Why are these constructs undefined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/949433/15168)

Comment: Does modifying this appease the standard and make the behavior defined? `i = (++i, i);`

Comment: @Chris: yes, but `++i` works the same (no assignment).  There is a sequence point such that the LHS of the comma operator is fully evaluated before the RHS is evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.1p2](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.1p2) or [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.3.1p2](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.3.1p2) :

> The value of the operand of the prefix ++ operator is incremented. The result is the new value of the operand after incrementation. The expression ++E is equivalent to (E+=1). [...]

From [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.2p3](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.2p3) or [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.16.2p3](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.16.2p3) :

> A compound assignment of the form E1 op = E2 is equivalent to the simple assignment expression E1 = E1 op (E2), except that the lvalue E1 is evaluated only once [...]

So we have `i = (i = i + 1);`, where the two `i` are evaluated once.

From [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16p3](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16p3) or [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.16p3](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.16p3) :

> An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by the left operand. An assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment,111) but is not an lvalue. The type of an assignment expression is the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion. The side effect of updating the stored value of the left operand is sequenced after the value computations of the left and right operands. The evaluations of the operands are unsequenced.

Now we start the engine. Let's mark them `i₁ = (i₂ = i₃ + 1);` just to know to which `i` I am referring to.

So updating `i₂` is sequenced after computation `i₃ + 1`.

And updating `i₁` is sequenced after *computation* `i₂ = i₃ + 1`.

But! Updating `i₁` and updating `i₂` are *unsequenced*. We do not know "when" the side effect of updating `i₂` will happen relative to the value computation of the value of the expression `i₂ = i₃ + 1`. `i₂` could be updated right after, or could be updated at *the next sequence point*, which is at `;`.

But there is no sequence point after `i₂ = i₃ + 1`. Updating of `i₁` is after *computing* `i₂ = i₃ + 1`, but is not sequenced with updating `i₂`. At the time of updating `i₁` the side effect of updating `i₂` is still "hanging", "to do". Because updating `i₁` and `i₂` is unsequenced, this is why it's undefined behavior.

Comment: OP talks about new stuff in C17, but this is C11.

Answer (score 2):

> At least for what I know here the incremented value of i should be used in the full expression, so we again have two side effects but now the side effect result of the pre-increment operator must be sequenced before the side effect result of the assignment operator, right?

Nope.  The `=` operator does not introduce a sequence point.

`++i` *evaluates* to the current value of `i` plus 1, but the *side effect* of updating `i` does not have to be applied immediately upon evaluation or before the assignment.  The following is a perfectly valid order of evaluation:

```
t0 <- i + 1
i <- t0
i <- i + 1
```

`i = ++i` is just as undefined as `i = i++`.  Pre- vs. post-increment (or decrement) doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Thabks for your answer man!